# Implementing Firebase Auth With React Native + react-native-oauth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, react-native

I want to authenticate users w/ Twitter in my React Native app. I'm using the react-native-oauth library https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth

I just want to make sure I'm going about this in the most effective way.

First things first I add firebase to my app in a `config/constants` file

```js
import firebase from 'firebase'

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "MY-API-KEY",
    authDomain: "MY-AUTH-DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "MY-DATABASE-URL",
    storageBucket: "MY-STORAGE-BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "MY-MESSAGING-ID"
});

const ref = firebase.database().ref()
const firebaseAuth = firebase.auth()

export { ref, firebaseAuth }
```

Then I install the react-native-oauth library

Now, in my `redux/authentication`I would probably do something like this where I eventually dispatch an action that saves the response object in my redux authentication state to use later.

```js
import OAuthManager from 'react-native-oauth';

const manager = new OAuthManager('Nimbus') // I'm sort of confused on what the name of the app should be. Is it just the name of the app when I ran react-native init? Or something else?

export default function handleAuthWithFirebase () {

    // Some redux thunk

    return function (dispatch, getState) {
        dispatch(authenticating());
        manager.configure({
            twitter: {
                consumer_key: 'SOME_CONSUMER_KEY',
                consumer_secret: 'SOME_CONSUMER_SECRET'
            },
        });

        manager.authorize('twitter', {scopes: 'profile email'})
            .then(resp => dispatch(getProfile(resp))) // Save response object
            .catch(err => console.log('There was an error'));

        // Do some other stuff like pushing a new route, etc.
    }
}
```

Then finally, in `SplashContainer.js` I would add this to the `handleSignIn` method (ultimately called by the presentational component).

```js
import React, { PropTypes, Component } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'

// Import function
import { handleAuthWithFirebase } from '~/redux/modules/authentication'
import { Splash } from '~/components'

export default class SplashContainer extends Component {
    handleSignIn = () => {
        // Sign in user with Twitter
        handleAuthWithFirebase.bind(this);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <Splash handleSignIn={this.handleSignIn}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Sorry, I know it was sort of a lot but just want to make sure I'm implementing this correctly. Any suggestions to improve the flow would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you check authenticate twitter with this package

[https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin ?](https://github.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-twitter-signin)